# Using try-catch to catch string input of fractions from JTextField in Java

Tags: java, string, try-catch, fractions

I have the string input from a JTextField, It will have to be a fractional input with numbers, separated by a single '/'.

I need to throw an error when a user inputs a string incorrectly; so far I can match the pattern but the exception won't get thrown. No idea what I'm doing wrong or if there is an easier way to do it, (I need to use try-catch though);

```
public void setInputData(String strFrac1, String strFrac2, String oper)
{
String test1, test2;
test1 = strFrac1;
test2 = strFrac2;

try 
{
test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)");
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);   
}


String[] fraction2 = strFrac2.split("/");
String[] fraction1 = strFrac1.split("/");


  //This will fill up a single array with the numbers and operators we need to use
  for (int i = 0 ; i <= 1; i++)
  {
    fractions[i] = fraction1[i];
    if (i == 0 || i == 1)
    {
      fractions[i + 2] = fraction2[i];
    }
  }

  fractions[4] = oper;

  return();
 }
```

Am I using the wrong catcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)");
```

will return a boolean

you can explicitily throw an exception

```
try 
{
if(!test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)"))
     throw new NumberFormatException();
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) 
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with the line

```
test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)");
```

It will return either `true` or `false`. But will not throw any `exception` .

to do this you can check the boolean value of `mathes` method

```
if(!test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)")
    // show the dialog
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to throw the exception when it does not match the pattern, then you need to throw it explicitly. The signature of `matches` method is

```
public boolean matches(String regex)
```

This means it will return `true` or `false`

so if your pattern matches the string input, then it will return `true` or it will return `false`.

To solve your problem, you can do,

```
 if(test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)")){
 // domeSomething
 }else {
  throw new NumberFormatException();
 }
```

This is the case where you have to use `try-catch`, if you don't want to use it, 
then you can simply show `MessageDialog` as follows

```
 if(test1.matches("(d+)(p/)(d+)")){
  //doSomething
  }else{
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ALERT!",   JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);   

  }
```